# How to keep a single activity instance but be able to update the view?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my situation, there is one case in which I need to make sure the activity only runs one at a time.

I found if I set the `LauchMode` of the activity, I can reach the single instance aim, but it won't update the view of the activity.

This activity is launched by `startActivityForResult`, and we send the URI with the intent to the activity.

Let's discuss with this certain case:

- gallery - lauch this activity with imageA.
- camera - lauch this activity with imageB.

My request is not to destroy the old activity, but the activity that just received the new intent infomation should refresh the view.

---

I found a new method, `onNewIntent`.
This method can refresh the intent before resume. I will try it.

Comment: Why is so important that the activity maintains alive? I think it's impossible.

Comment: this is because if there is two activity instance, will cause some problem in our app.   so i need to make sure,it is single instance.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can have an Activity with a manifest attribute of singleInstance.
As soon as the activity is relaunched , onResume gets called. You can update the view with the new image and invalidate the older View.

```
<activity ..
      android:launchMode= "singleInstance" />
```

Comment: my image info is store in the Intent.but i get the intent info with getIntent() is the old one.  maybe it is the key question.  thank you for your reply.

Comment: Is there any way to set the activity in the task activity stack of which activity start it.    <activity ..
      android:launchMode= "singleInstance" />  ;this method will start a new task with the activity.

Comment: A "singleInstance" activity, on the other hand, permits no other activities to be part of its task. It's the only activity in the task. Thus, use android:launchMode="singleTask".

Answer (score 41):

In your manifest, use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` instead of `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`. Using **singleInstance** only returns to the existing instance if it is at the top of the stack. **singleTask**, on the other hand, return to the existing instance of the activity, as it is always at the root of the task.

Then, when your instance is launched, override [`onNewIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) to update your UI according to the new intent.

Refer to [the Andorid documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for details.

Comment: I agree that both mode allows only one instance of the Activity but your interpretation of the difference is wrong.

Comment: @ben75 is right: The "singleTask" and "singleInstance" modes also differ from each other in only one respect: A "singleTask" activity allows other activities to be part of its task. It's always at the root of its task, but other activities (necessarily "standard" and "singleTop" activities) can be launched into that task. A "singleInstance" activity, on the other hand, permits no other activities to be part of its task. It's the only activity in the task.

Answer (score 4):

Be careful when using `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in multiple activities application.
Here is my test on Pixel 4XL (Android 10)
Example, we have 3 activities (without declare `taskAffinity`)

- `A` (entry activity)
- `B` (start from A)
- `C` (**singleInstance**, start from B)

If we start `A->B->C`. Now A,B in a task and C in a different task.
From C, press back -> will see B, press back -> will see A, press back -> app close. Everything working efine.

**However**, if we start `A->B->C` then press `Home` -> app go to to background.
Now there is 2 situations

- User open app again from Recent app.

  - User will see **C screen**. Press back -> **app will close** (don't go to B)
- User open app again by click on app icon

  - User will see **B screen**. Press back -> will see **A**, press back -> **app will close** (don't go to **C**)

The behaviour after open application is different between both case. But in both case, the application is **always available** in `Recent` app and you **never able to** remove application from Recent app (after remove it will appear again). Only able to remove it by Force stop in Setting.
If you run `adb shell dumpsys activity activities`, you will see that activities still exist in `Stack`, but you can not go back to it.

#### Another case

If we start `A->B->C->A`. Now A,B,A in a task and C in a different task (A is current visible to user).
From A, press back -> will see B (**not C**), press back-> will see A, press back -> will see C, press back -> app will close. (at least here we can go back to `C`)

Now if, we start `A->B->C->A` then press `Home`. In both case, user open app again by Recent or click on app icon, user will see A screen. Press back -> will see B, press back -> will see A, press back -> app will close (never see C screen)

### Another note

The above example, although application run on 2 tasks but in `Recent apps`, it only show 1 task.
If you set the `taskAffinity`, in the `Recent apps`, you will see 2 tasks. In that case, you can choose the task  which contain activity that you want to display but when you press back, it just go back to the activity in **same task** or close app (not able to go back to activity in another task).
Also, if you click on app icon to open app again, we have the same behavior like above demo.

I think `singleTask` and `singleTop` is less complex than `singleInstance`, so if it is enough for solve your problem, consider to use them instead of `singleInstance`