# How to make single copy of an activity over entire application

Tags: android, android-activity

Here i have opened activity in following order
A->B->C->D
now i just want to re-launch activity B so that order becomes:
A->C->D->B

can anyone please tell me that how can i achieve this state in android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tell us what you have tried to archive it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep a single activity instance but be able to update the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132939/how-to-keep-a-single-activity-instance-but-be-able-to-update-the-view)

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your manifest file for activity B:

```
<activity 
   android:name=".B"
   android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

Comment: whenever activity's launch mode is defined as single task then all the activity in between is destroyed and same is happening with me.
When i am launching Activity B from D then C and D are destroying

Comment: In that case you can try this : remove the launchMode="singleTask" and use : FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag whenever call an intent to B.

Answer (score 0):

now you have A B C D in your app
try the following below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(xxx.this, B.class);    
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);      
startActivity(intent);
```

also check file in [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

Comment: A->B->C->D
when i am launching B from D then on backPressed() app is closing